# Node.js join query error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I use express.js and sequelize, mysql

## DB

```
A : { id: 1, name: ... }
B : { A_id: 1, name: name1 }, { A_id: 1, name: name2 }
```

## models/A.js

```
A.association = models => {
 A.hasMany(models.B, { foreignKey: 'A_id' });
};
const { B } = require('../models');
A.get = _id => {
 return A.findAll({
  where: { id: _id },
  include: [{ model: B }],
 });
};
```

## models/B.js

```
B.association = models => {
 B.belongsTo(models.A, { foreignKey: 'A_id' });
};
```

## routes/test.js

```
A.get(1).then(record => { console.log(record); });
```

## executed query

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, B.A_id, B.name
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.id = B.A_id
WHERE A.id=1;
```

## result

**should have { A_id: 1, name: name2 }**

```
[A: {
 id: 1,
 name: ...,
 Bs: [{ A_id: 1, name: name1 }]
}];
```

What is the problem? query is fine. It returns data 'name1, name2'

Why Sequelize method doesn't get all of B column?

Comment: This is due to column has been same from both tables. So try to use alias if both table have same column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to column has been same from both tables. So try to use alias if both table have same column name.

It should be something like this.

```
return A.findAll({
  where: { id: _id },
  include: [{ model: B }, attributes[["name", "nameb"]],
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for comment :) but it doesn't work. I modified. *include: [{ model: B, attributes: [['name': 'bname']] }]* It just rename column. not return name2.